# Is there a way to pass an alias column name in a nested sub-query, via WHERE IN statement, to the UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case, where-clause

I came across this -
[Using ALIAS column in WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515241/using-alias-column-in-where-statement) recently and I understand why the WHERE clause is giving me an error but I can't seem to figure out any other way to write my nested query. The SELECT sub-query runs completely fine by itself.

The error is as follows:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'actual_start_time' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'
```

> Table Structure:
>
> Students:    student_id    student_name    login_time    logout_time
>
> Tests:    test_id    test_start_time    test_end_time
>
> TestStats:    test_id    student_id     test_duration

```
UPDATE test_stats
SET test_duration = datediff(hour, actual_start_time - actual_end_time)
WHERE (actual_start_time, actual_end_time)
IN (
SELECT
CASE
WHEN (s.login_time > t.test_start_time) THEN s.login_time
ELSE t.test_start_time
END AS actual_start_time,
CASE
WHEN (s.logout_time < t.test_end_time) THEN s.logout_time
ELSE t.test_end_time
END AS actual_end_time
FROM tests AS t, students AS s, test_stats AS ts
WHERE t.test_id = ts.test_id and s.student_id = ts.student_id);
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your DATEDIFF? datediff(hour, actual_start_time, actual_end_time)

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax (there is not `FROM` in the `UPDATE` in MySQL).  Please tag with the database you are really using or explain why you are using knowingly incorrect syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not too familiar with MySQL but I did try using FROM with UPDATE and it presented a syntax error on the SQL Workbench.
PS - I am using MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.43

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please suggest an alternative query if possible. I will be glad to accept it as a solution.

Comment: @JimJimson I don't think that's an issue, on the contrary, DATEDIFF(hour, actual_start_time, actual_end_time) generates an error -

Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be what you want:

```
UPDATE test_stats ts JOIN
       tests t
       ON t.test_id = ts.test_id  JOIN
       students s
       ON s.student_id = ts.student_id
SET test_duration = timestampdiff(hour,
                                  GREATEST(s.login_time, t.test_start_time),
                                  LEAST(s.logout_time, t.test_end_time)
                                 );
```

Comment: I have suggested some edits. The edited version works like a charm. Thanks!